# Python process is taking long time

Tags: python

Actually I am importing serial data from arduino and I am using python to move the current location of the mouse at specific pixels. My problem is whenever my if statement is true for even one second, python performs the function which is (mousemove) to move the mouse for more than 5 to 10 seconds. I am getting delayed response everytime. I want the program to work instantly as reading changes so I can move mouse smoothly.

My code:

```
import pyautogui
import serial
irData = serial.Serial('com3',9600)
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

def movemouse( int ):
print(dataint)
pyautogui.moveTo(500,500)
return;


while 1:

    while(irData.inWaiting()==0):
      pass
      data = irData.readline() #collecting data from serial port and  assigning into data varibale        

      try:
        dataint = int(data) # Return an integer value from a string
        x, y = pyautogui.position()      # Assign the mose position into varibale x and y
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' +  str(y).rjust(4)

     #It allows the program to take same amount of space inspite of having different integer values as in unit or thousands and show it in proper x & y format. 
         if dataint >=120:
           movemouse(dataint)                         

         else:
           print(dataint)   #Print the current mouse coordinates.            
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Done"
```

Comment: To begin with, this doesn't look like Python code. **1**: It has curly brackets and **2**: The tab identation is completely off.  Try fixing your code and it might be easier (more fun) to help out.

Comment: Not only is indentation messed up there is a `try` without an `except` and obviously code is missing. "taking long time" frequently equates to a messed up loop and if you don't show us the messed code, how can we help?

Comment: I did some changes.Previously it was not aligned properly and this is complete coding and from python.Can you look through why the loop is giving me delayed response.

Comment: Your code is still in an unreadable and not executable state. You have to fix the indentation at least. It is very important and shoyld be four spaces per level.

Comment: How about now? I tried to fix the identation but I don't exactly know what I am doing wrong.